# Как в андроиде подключиться к WCF-сервису?

Tags: java, android, wcf

Как в *андроиде* подключиться к *WCF*-сервису?

Comment: Накатить поверх WCF - WebAPI? Потому что WCF может использовать например TCP протокол вместо HTTP.

Comment: я в этом деле новичок, если объясните буду признателен

Comment: Очень много всего объяснять - учи матчасть.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.